# How do I change cookie settings?

Tags: support, profile-page

I clicked "Accept all cookies" on the recent cookie settings popup, but I would like to open that menu again and update my preferences, can someone help me find where in the settings I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: In the footer under the Company section.

Comment: I guess it makes sense it is not in your user profile with all the other settings, the cookie settings need to be able to be set regardless of you being logged in or not. I wonder how it is remembered. Surely not using a cookie? :)

Comment: @Gimby Yes, someone mentioned that you can just delete them from your browser and SO will ask again, which makes sense now that I think about it. But, it is still good to have direct access to the popup from the front page.

Comment: For [Winter Bash](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/), you can even get a hat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the footer you'll find a link called *Cookie Settings* under the Company column. When you click it the dialog with the settings will open and you can amend your choices.

Here is the screenshot to give you a visual clue where to look:

[image]

Comment: As of today, the first day I tried it, the click on "Cookie Settings" in the footer does nothing. As of today I am getting a cookie dialog on every page and every refresh of a page.

Comment: @RiggsFolly there certainly is a bug, reported on either MSE or MSO but I can't find it right now. Might also involve Firefox, not sure what you're using.

Comment: I am using FF @rene

Comment: [suggestion 1 in this answer seems to fix it for me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424346/2310830) disabling DuckDuckGo Essential, get the next cookie dialog, select whichever option, then re-enable DDGo

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is too bad we need workarounds, specially when those workarounds involve disabling privacy features, to get a decent working site.