# How do I make Stack Overflow stop asking for cookie preferences?

Tags: discussion, cookies

Every time I restart my browser and then browse to Stack Overflow, I get the "accept all cookies" button covering the bottom half of my screen. If I go into customizing cookies, it knows that I've already set my preferences to "essential only", but to keep that setting I have to go through 3 popups and 4 clicks in the right place -- otherwise, I'm back to all cookies.

This has become the new nag screen. The site conveniently forgets that I don't want to be surveilled.

How can I set my cookie preferences once and for all?

Comment: Have you set your browser to clear browsing history/cookies on exit?

Comment: Have you found a solution? Because I am experiencing this as well and I don't clear cookies or anything else suggested here. I only have it on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 32):

There are a few reasons this could be happening.

### Security Extensions (Chrome, Firefox)

If you are using *DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials* with Chrome, try to disable site protections for this plugin.

1. Temporarily disable any browser security extensions that you use.
2. Reload the site and accept cookies.
3. (option) Re-enable security extensions.

This started happening to me beginning in the March/April 2023 time frame. It wasn't happening with any other website I visit regularly.

It's unclear which specific blocked resource may be the issue, but in the *Developer Tools Network* you can observe some of them.

After unblocking the resources, the decision to accept cookies will be saved for any future visits.

### Reset Cookies and Site Permissions (Chrome)

This is already covered in another answer, but open `chrome://settings` and search for *Cookies and other site data*.

1. Go to **See all site data and permissions**.
2. Search for stackoverflow.com
3. Select `Clear data` and `Reset permissions`.

If the decision to accept cookies is not saved because cookies are blocked or popups are blocked the site will keep opening the modal.

Comment: googletagmanager and doubleclick being blocked isn't the problem. I have them blocked and SE works just fine for me.

Comment: This appears to have worked for me on FF 122 Windows. Disabled DuckDuckGo Security Essentials, then went to SO, Clicked "Only Essential" and now the repeated cookie dialog appears to have taken the rest of the day off

Comment: Disabling UBlock did not resolve it for me, but disabling DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials did. After clicking the cooking dialog I can then re-enable DuckDuckGo and the dialog stays gone.

Comment: Disabling DuckDuckGo privacy essentials for the site worked for me as well

Answer (score 18):

Your cookie preferences are stored in a cookie, set to expire in 1 year. Stack Overflow is doing everything it should be doing in order to remember your preferences. When you are asked again about cookies, it's not remembering your preferences regarding "essential only", that's just the default.

If you delete your cookies, you are going to be asked again. If you're not intentionally deleting your cookies, you may have configured your browser to block cookies, or to automatically treat all cookies as session cookies. But this isn't Stack Overflow's fault, and it's not their problem to fix.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Now, the workaround for the OP:  Install a plugin such as Stylebot, and set `display: none;` for `.js-consent-banner`.  You'll never see it again (unless they change the element class) but you might not love the cookies being unset all the time.

Comment: I am not sure this is the correct answer. I've been experiencing the same thing as OP for a long time now and I don't clear or block cookies or anything on any site. Those sites where I want this behavior, I open in privacy mode. This is the only site having this problem.

Comment: Mine does it, every new tab,over and over, on the main site, but not on this Meta site. It's strange. Always hated the whole business, seems like a hammer to crack a nut (cookie consent in general, not stack)

Comment: uBlock Origin has a tool (picker) that can block that banner.

Comment: Yup. This recently (about 2 weeks ago) started happening to me and it's only on SO. I even cleared my data for SO an re-logged in with the same problem. If I accept my desired setting the dialog box goes away until I navigate to the next SO page.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this happens on all Stack Exchange sites (so the question could be a candidate for migration to Meta.SE).

Ironically, it seems that the only way to get this dialog to disappear is to set your browser to accept cookies(!), thus denying the very choice it purports to offer.

I discovered (when trying to use SO from an account I haven't configured for Stack Exchange) that the annoying overlay is unkillable unless you enable JavaScript, which certainly never used to be required for simply *reading* questions and answers as an anonymous user.  And then, it reappears on every access unless you accept a cookie to disable it.

This is a terrible experience for first-time users, who wouldn't necessarily be able to guess which combination of settings is required just to stop half the content being obscured.

It's particularly ironic that if you have a reasonably defensive default policy of never accepting cookies that you get bothered by this notice *that isn't even correct*.

Comment: The fact that you rejected cookies needs to be stores ___somewhere___. I mean, what did you expect?! How would the site know you rejected cookies, if you wipe everything and anything the site's stored? Also, who still blocks JavaScript? This isn't 2001. Solution: Set your browser to ___allow___ cookies on SE, and then reject them in the popup. That will ___only___ store the fact that you rejected cookies. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @Cerbrus: yes, that's what I did for my main browser (where I log in to SE), but that doesn't make it a less terrible new-user experience.

Comment: One would hope/expect that if the browser presents no cookies to the server, then it should be smart enough to omit the dialog?

Comment: It's not an SE issue. It's a client issue. Get your client configured properly and you'd be fine. A blanket ban on all cookies (and JS) is just not of this time.