# If I tell Stack Overflow I'll accept all cookies, why doesn't it remember that setting?

Tags: support, privacy, cookies

Stack Overflow and all related sites pop up the ever-present cookie warnings dictated by the European Union. OK, I get that this isn't Stack Overflow's fault.

But shouldn't they use a cookie to remember my cookie preferences? I get that if I was rejecting the cookies, I'd be stuck seeing the warning again and again, because there's no way to save my preference (in a totally secure and non-invasive way that cookies actually provide). But I'm not rejecting cookies. I'm telling Stack Overflow to use all the cookies. And it never ceases to ask me about my cookie preferences.

Comment: Yes, it is Stack Overflow's fault. It's entirely possible to not need a cookie consent pop-up. All they have to do is stop doing all that nasty, unnecessary user tracking. Aside from that, yes, if they've gone to the effort of getting your consent, they should use the cookies properly, otherwise what's the point?

Comment: Stack uses a third party cookie management system IIRC. If it's blocked by anything (ad blocker, Pi-hole or other DNS-based ad blockers, your ISP, your employer, your country, etc.), it doesn't persist. I highly recommend installing uBlock Origin; it outright blocks the cookie dialog, along with the various trackers used. So much better. Also worth noting that even if you do reject all, you don't actually reject all. You reject all non-essential cookies. Even if you reject, at least (but sadly, far from only) the login cookie and cookie with your cookie preferences is still stored

Comment: Related (possibly a duplicate): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416632

Comment: @Synchro I mean, I kind of like not having to login every time I open a new tab and visit Stack Overflow, which sometimes is hundreds of times a day.

Comment: *But I'm not rejecting cookies.* Are you sure? What are your browser settings regarding history and cookies? If it’s set to automatically delete/clear/block cookies then that will force the consent dialog to keep asking.

Comment: There is [a JavaScript requirement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#comment1200676_71208) (or was?).

Comment: Flagged a duplicate since IMO the answer to the linked question answers this one as well. It raises a different question: "why does SO store cookie preferences in a cookie and not in the user account settings?" But I don't think that's the question being asked.

Comment: @TylerH That's a common misconception. Session cookies usually count as "strictly necessary" (as in, the service will not work without them) and [don't require consent](https://gdpr.eu/cookies/).

Comment: @Synchro Sorry, I missed the "consent" part of your first comment. Thought you were arguing against all cookies.

Comment: I wouldn't be *that* silly 